# button image change color after disabling

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

My button image change color after disabling?

Despitve having:

```
button.adjustsImageWhenDisabled = false
```

Normally my image color is set by custom tintColor.

Why does button behave differently?
tintColor should be always the same, despite button state....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather disabling the button, change it's userInteraction property to false.

```swift
button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: Yeah! It does work, but why button.isEnabled = false change the color of an image?

Comment: In Swift if you disable any item then uikit make it faded kind of item to represent this item is disable to user.

Answer (score 1):

In interface builder have you tried setting the state config to disabled and set the disabled image in there?

or do it in the code with..

```
button.setImage(<UIImage>, for: .disabled)
```

Comment: i don;t use interface builder, everything from code

Comment: You can set it in code using the line that I have added.

Comment: it doesn't change anything, i've alredy tired it before :(

Comment: @JanekPodwysocki first set the property, then make your button `.isEnabled = false`